# I want to show a chapter page number from 15 to 25 - barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Tags: android, pdf

I'm using [barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer), and suffering from an issue that is I want to show a chapter page number from 15 to 25, how it will be? I can start a chapter page number using `.defaultPage(15)` but how can I finish on page 25? Is it possible? Here is sample code:

```
private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
pdfFileName = assetFileName;
pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
        .defaultPage(15)
        .onPageChange(this)
        .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
        .onLoad(this)
        .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
        .load();
}
```

Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show some pages, mention them on pages function as followed, it will show pages from 15 to 25.

```
.pages(15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)
```

Below is complete function.

```
private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
pdfFileName = assetFileName;
pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
        .defaultPage(15)
        .onPageChange(this)
        .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
        .onLoad(this)
        .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
        .pages(15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)
        .load();
}
```